# How to delete multiple selected rows from array in angular

Tags: javascript, angular, angular8

I have tables and i want to delete multiple selected rows on button click.I am getting below array on button click. PFA for array..

Comment: do you using ngFor in html to display the array

Comment: Please add the code for this component to understand it What you have already done?

Comment: No i dont have any loop in html, i have pasted only button in HTML. I am getting selected rows values from tableModel like below code 
const selectedValueIndex = Object.keys(this.staticValuemodel.rowsSelected);

Comment: I am pasting output of this.staticValuemodel.rowsSelected

Answer (score 0):

Your loop should be on Id bases and findIndex in it's loop and then splice the array element.

It should be something like below

Comment: I have edited my question and pasted all code again..can u plz review again..Yes you are right its deleting wrong keys

Answer (score 0):

```
deleteAllRows() {         
    this.staticValuemodel.rowsSelected.forEach(key => {
      this.StaticData.records.splice(key, 1);      
    });  
    this.populateStaticTable(this.StaticData.records);  

  }
```

As your `this.staticValuemodel.rowsSelected` output pic is confusing if its Object or Array.( better send a screenshot with google chrome console )

Comment: Its an array with multiple objects

Comment: share me what  property it contains

Answer (score 0):

Some like:

```
//get an array with the index of elements selected, e.g. [0,3]
const rowsSelects=Object.keys(this.staticValuemodel.rowsSelected); 

//filter the data
this.StaticData.records=this.StaticData.records
   .filter((x,index)=>rowSelects.indexOf(index)<0)
```

Yes, filter can has a "second argument" that is the index of the element